# My laravel recaptcha not working, how to integrate?

Tags: laravel, captcha

I added google recpatcha which was working in login form . Then I used auth::routes for forgot password reset. This made recaptcha to not work.

Comment: Here is the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66720254/google-recaptcha-with-laravel

Answer (score 1):

```
if someone is still pulling their hair because of this issue just remove the 'recaptcha' in validation rule.

use

'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required'
instead of

'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'
see http://tuts.codingo.me/google-recaptcha-in-laravel-application/
```

**or**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" 
           data-sitekey="{{env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY')}}">
</div>
```

Comment: I replaced 'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required'
with 

'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha' still not working